# FreeRTOS and global pointer

Tags: freertos

Can anyone suggest if "FreeRTOS" uses the global pointer (in case of "MIPS" architecture) when context switching (from the kernel side)?

Comment: I'm not sure that MIPS are supported officially by freertos, are you referring to a particular fork? What do you mean by "the global pointer"?

Comment: Yes, FreeRTOS doesn't provide port for MIPS yet, I ment SFR # 28

Comment: "global pointer" is not a FreeRTOS term. Please elaborate.